# Word to say keep up credibility of someone's recommedation?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

One of my acquaintance who has a very high credibility recommended me to someone for a service I offer...

I am writing a mail to thank him. I wish to convey that "I will work hard to ensure that his recommendation is highly appreciated by the client".

How do I do write?

Comment: It's primarily opinion based Masade. There cannot be one answer to this. Also, do you want that *word* as a subject of the mail? Or you need an entire paragraph? Or a line? Add some more text to your question.

Comment: I am probably looking for a sentence. I could not find the relevant tag.

Comment: ELL won't write this for you. However, we can provide idioms or expressions to help you find the right words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a letter writing service.

Comment: @curiousdannii et al. - "How do I do write?" could mean, "How do I write the letter?" But it could also mean, "What is a good idiomatic English phrase to convey this idea?" The former may be off-topic, but the latter is a legitimate ELL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to say this, but the English expression that first came to my mind is ***live up to***. NOAD says the idiom "live up to" means to "fulfill expectations," and Wordnik says it means "to meet expectations". M-W defines it as "to act or be in accordance with."

In Manik Joshi's book *Speak English Sentences Everyday*, this example sentence is used:

> *I will live up to the enormous trust you have placed in us*.

So, you could write:

> "I will work hard to ensure that I *live up to* your positive recommendation".

This would convey that you don't want the client to be ultimately disappointed in your performance after receiving such a glowing recommendation.

Comment: Glad to help, but please unaccept my answer and wait a day or so. [Here's why](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). My answer might "work," but someone else may write something better.